# jQuery 'swiper' plugin mysteriously not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slider, swiper.js

I'm trying to figure out why the slider/swiper plugin on [this page](http://pftest.byethost11.com/) refuses to run no matter what I do - I have tried calling the script in the DOM with both $(function(){ and window.onload as the [plugin's author](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php) recommends as well as changing the order of plugins, attempting to put it between/before/after plugins ect. but it either breaks the other plugins or otherwise just not work outright.

Using Firefox's Firebug for the first time I also notice that this script is highlighted specifically in red as indicating something is obviously wrong, but being a novice at jQuery debugging I'm having a difficult time figuring out what exactly..

I had it working fine on another test page, so I assume it must be a incompatibility somewhere with one or more of the current jQuery plugins I am using?

Comment: Anybody? :( I am at a complete loss here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a magic:) You have wrong order of swiper's HTML elements. You have swiper-wrapper>swiper-container, but it should be swiper-container>swiper-wrapper. Swiper-wrapper should be inside of swiper-container